# How can I remove multiple forward slashes from a URL using Apache Rewrite Rules?

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

For example, I'd like to change

```
http://www.foo.com/bar//baz
```

to

```
http://www.foo.com/bar/baz
```

Answer (score 3):

Apache treats multiple slashes as single slashes.

You can 301 redirect double-slashed URLs to the correct URL using mod_rewrite in .htaccess:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//+(.*)$`

`RewriteRule / http://www.example.com/%1/%2 [R=301,L]`

or using RedirectMatch:

`RedirectMatch 301 ^(.*)//+(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/$2`

Either of these snippets will replace two or more contiguous slashes with a single slash.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]
```